# Android UriMatcher doesn't match wildcards

Tags: android, regex, android-contentprovider

I have a `ContentProvider` and I need to match some `URIs` containing `UUIDs` as wildcards.

**UriMatcher from ContentProvider:**

```
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_NOTIFICATIONS = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + BASE_PATH_NOTIFICATIONS);
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_USERS  = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + BASE_PATH_USERS);

private static final int NOTIFICATIONS = 40;
private static final int USER_ID = 70;

private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

static
{
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH_NOTIFICATIONS, NOTIFICATIONS);
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH_USERS + "/*", USER_ID);
}
```

**Query Code for NOTIFICATIONS:**

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_NOTIFICATIONS));
 return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), uri, projection, null, null, null);
```

**Query Code for USER_ID:**

```
String userId = "73279386-5459-4316-9ff9-7c6b7b84029a";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_USERS + "/" + userId);
return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), uri, projection, null, null, null);
```

From the above UriMatcher, the **NOTIFICATIONS** URI matches, but the **USER_ID** does not. Any idea what could be wrong here ? Worth noting is that when I used to have integers instead of UUIDs for representing users and used to have # instead of * in the UriMatcher, everything worked as intended. After switching to the wildcard, the matcher stopped matching the URIs containing UUIDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the order in which you add the URIs counts. If you have set like below, USER_DETAILS won't be recognized anymore. You have to switch the order and add USER_DETAILS first.

```
sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH_USERS + "/*", USER_ID);
sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH_USERS + "/details", USER_DETAILS);
```